# Array values output incorrectly

Tags: c++

I am having a very simple function to input values. But I am getting a wired output. I get different values to what I am inserting? What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void testFunc(float arr[], int sizeOfArray);

int main() {
    int sizeOfArray = 4;
    float arrA[] = {};
    float arrB[] = {};
    
    cout << "1st array VALUES" << endl;
    testFunc(arrA, 4);
    cout << "A -> ";
    for(int i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++){
        cout << arrA[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "2nd array VALUES" << endl;
    testFunc(arrB, 4);
    cout << endl << "B -> ";
    for(int i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++){
        cout  << arrB[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

void testFunc(float arr[], int sizeOfArray) {
    for(int i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++){
        cout << "Insert val " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not `C` code.  Second, your arrays have 0 entries.  What are you expecting to accomplish by accessing elements that are out-of-bounds?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry about that I just updated few seconds before you corrected that. Thank yo0u :)

Comment: You have not initialized the array and trying to print the value, hence it returns or prints garbage value

Comment: You should provide sample input, as well as the “bad” output you are seeing.

Comment: @AshishMJ Thanks you :) So `float arrA[] = {}` is the fault and `float arrA[4];` is the fix?

Comment: Might also want to set a default size if this isn’t a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @Fergoso -- Arrays are fixed size in C++.  Once the size is 0, it will remain 0.  Second, C++ has something called `undefined behavior`.  Your code could have crashed if built with different compilation options or built using a different compiler.  Does the C++ book you're learning from have any examples like what you posted?  I bet it doesn't.  Learning C++ cannot be done from cheat sheets or off-the-cuff.  It is one of the most difficult languages to learn, and only using good peer-reviewed C++ books is the way to learn such a language.

Comment: Thank you so much all!!!!! I understand the cause now. :) +1 to all 3 of you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float arrA[] = {}` creates an array of floats with `0` size. When you iterate over it, you access an out of bound memory in here:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++);
```

You can list initialize an array and not specify the size of an array, using braces `{...}`. But in such case, the size is deduced from the elements in the list. You have empty list.

For example:

```
float arr[] = {}; // Empty
float arr[4]; // Four elements, all default initialized
float arr[] = {3.14, 1.61}; // Two elements, specified values
float arr[4] = {3.14, 1.61}; // Four elements, last two are value initialized
```

You will benefit from taking a look at these articles:

[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

[C++ Containers Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)